# Meta tags not showing on front page drupal

Tags: drupal-7

I'm using the module "metatag" to make my website SEO friendly. This works very well for all pages except the front page.

I go to modules -> Meta tags -> Settings -> Global: Front page

There I set a description. But this description isn't shown if you search the site directly in google. All other pages are working great, with the correct description.

When I look at the source, I see no meta data included at the front page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to assign a node to be 'front'. Otherwise the meta won't show.

Go to  modules -> Meta tags -> Settings ->

add meta tag here BY Path for your default front page path.

Answer (score 3):

You need to print those metatags with this line:

```
<?php print render($page['content']['metatags']); ?>
```